# Next JS: The requested resource isn't a valid image error

Tags: next.js

⨯ The requested resource isn't a valid image for /assets/menuItems/Gan-fan.webp received text/html; charset=utf-8

I am getting this error when using the next image. I searched it up, and ChatGPT said to ensure that paths are okay. I tried it, but it didn't work. Pictures are visible on development but not visible on the production. Only the alt text is visible.

```
<Flex
              key={item.name}
              position="relative"
              width="100%"
              borderRadius="lg"
              direction="column"
              mb="4"
            >
              <Box
                position="relative"
                width="100%"
                paddingBottom="100%"
                borderRadius="lg"
                overflow="hidden"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item.image}
                  alt={item.name}
                  style={{
                    objectFit: "cover",
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "0",
                    left: "0",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                  }}
                  fill
                />
                {badgeType === "PICTURE" && (
                  <Badge
                    zIndex="4"
                    position="absolute"
                    top="0"
                    right="0"
                    bg="#dfa25f"
                    color="white"
                    m="16px"
                  >
                    <Text fontSize="xs">{item.categories.join(", ")}</Text>
                  </Badge>
                )}
              </Box>
```

I tried searching it up on ChatGPT and in the next documentation, but I didn't find much. Maybe there is an error with the web format, but it is low possible because other comments with web pages are visible.

Also i tried `const nextConfig = { images: { unoptimized: true } };`
from stack over flow but it didn't work
also i tried method from stack overflow but it didn't work

putting instead of /assets/ use /public//assets/